# Show that $\dim(\operatorname{Im} S+\operatorname{Im} T)\leq7$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V,W$ be vector spaces and subspace $U\subset V$ with $\dim U=3$, $\dim V=5$
>   and let $T:V\to W$, $S:V\to W$ be linear maps s.t. $S(u)=T(u)\quad \forall u\in   
> U$
>
> Show that $\dim(\operatorname{Im} S+\operatorname{Im} T)\leq7$

I'm trying to figure out how to use $S(u)=T(u)\quad \forall u\in U$.
I know that $$\dim V=\dim \operatorname{ker}T+\dim \operatorname{Im}T$$ and also$$\dim (\operatorname{Im}S+\operatorname{Im}T)=\dim \operatorname{Im}S+\dim \operatorname{Im}T-\dim (\operatorname{Im}S\cap \operatorname{Im}T)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{u_1,u_2,u_3,v_4,v_5\}$ be a basis of $V$ where $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ is a basis of $U$.

Then, $\{S(u_1),S(u_2),S(u_3),S(v_4),S(v_5),T(v_4),T(v_5)\}$ spans $\operatorname{Im} S + \operatorname{Im} T$, so $\dim(\operatorname{Im} S + \operatorname{Im} T) \le 7$.